# Is it possible to change the Raphael JS (or SVG) coordinate system?

Tags: svg, raphael, vml

I'm playing around with the RaphaelJS library, and I notice that it's very pixel-oriented.  I'd like to draw something that scales with the viewport.  Is it possible to redefine the canvas coordinate system to run from 0 to 1, so if I draw a circle centered at [0.5, 0.5], it remains in the middle of its container even as the container's size changes?

This may be more of an SVG/VML question, since even if Raphael has no way to do this, I can always access the underlying svg element directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but I found a way to get some of what I was looking for.  If you ignore the width/height parameters, or use '100%', then the setViewBox command can be used to set up your own coordinate system.

```
var canvas = Raphael("container");
canvas.setViewBox(0, 0, 1, 1, true);
```

The problem of course is that this scales everything, including strokes, backgrounds, etc.  This makes it difficult to have things like stroke-widths other than 1px.

Comment: Actually, by using [`vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/examples/non-scaling-stroke.svg) you can get 1px strokes regardless of the transformation.

Comment: Not sure that's natively supported in Raphael

Comment: You can add it by $(SomeRaphaelElement.node).css({'vector-effect':'non-scaling.stroke'});

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating a Raphael paper stretched to fill a div with animated size change, both with and without setViewBox http://jsfiddle.net/fa9zbnyd/2/